# Docker настройка

Tags: linux, nginx, docker-compose

При настройки docker появляется ошибка:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (1: Operation not permitted)

2020/05/14 10:14:17 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (1: Operation not permitted)
```

Файл docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:80:80
    volumes:
    - ./app:/var/www/html
    - ./configs/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Файл default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
        fastcgi_buffers 500 512k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 1200;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 1200;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 200;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

}
```

Когда в консоли пишу

```
docker up -d
docker ps -a
```

Получаю результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Docker-пользователь nginx не имеет прав записи в ваш каталог `logs/nginx`. Сделай ему chmod 777 или что-то типа того

Comment: @andreymal,  В консоли пишу `docker exec -it bf2c0080adf1 bash`.  В ответ получаю:  Error response from daemon: Container bf2c0080adf13ef156bc37ae20b09727f39d7cdf8ec43533e9fe8c28b3b5e1fb is not running

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуй добавить строчку в docker-compose.yml `user: root:root`
2. Попробуй `systemctl restart docker`